# How to get Java WebStart to use the Windows certificate store for downloading jar files?

Tags: java, ssl, https, java-web-start

I've got the following situation: We've got an application using Java Webstart that is deployed on customer sites. The server that distributes the application is also installed on the customer sites. Now some of the customers have asked us to use SSL to better integrate the application into their existing systems (which use SSL exclusively), and at least some of them use their own certification chains.

In order to keep the support to a minimum my original goal was to require the customers to install their root certificate into a single keystore. However the application is launched from a third-party app, which uses a .NET dll (supplied by us) to start our application, which is now also required to use SSL to download the jnlp file from the server. So my current solution to the problem of using only a single keystore is to simply use the Windows keystore in our own Java application using

```
KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT");
```

and then feeding it to the SSLSocketFactory. Moreover the .NET dll can also load the jnlp file without any problems this way.

However the last remaining step is to get Java WebStart to download the jar files from the server without having to install the certificate into one of the java keystores, which so far I have failed to achieve. So this is my questions:

Is there a way to configure Java WebStart (only the Java WebStart program itself) to use the Windows certificate store to validate certificates?

Comment: Just an update for others who are interested in this topic: So far I did not find a solution to get this working. However if you've got no other dependencies (like .NET in my case) you can also try to load the store Java WebStart is using by checking the system properties (when run via WebStart).

Comment: I think my problem would be exactly solved by your partial solutions in which you wrote "use the Windows keystore in our own Java application using KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT");
and then feeding it to the SSLSocketFactory."  Can you explain how to feed it to SSLSocketFactory?  I've not had success figuring that out.